# two STI hierarchies and polymorphic association(s) between them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following:

- Reseller hierarchy, STI, tree structure in the resellers DB table. BaseReseller is the parent, and I have a few concrete subtypes like Agent, Reseller, IPSP, etc.
- User STI - the base is User model, and have a few concrete subtypes like ResellerUser, etc.
- The logic is that any Reseller will have an admin user administering the Reseller, e.g. an Agent having an agent admin, an IPSP having an IPSP admin user, and so on. The admin user is validated upon creation of the Reseller, cannot create Reseller without an admin user.
- I am trying to assign a ResellerUser to a Reseller. The ResellerUser instance is create beforehand, and selected from a ResellerUser dropdown upon creation of a concrete Reseller.
- After executing the create controller method, in the DB we have:

resellers table

```
admin_id = 7 (correct)
type = Reseller (also correct)
```

users table

```
owner_id = 6 (correct)
owner_type = BaseReseller (is this OK?)
type = ResellerUser (correct)
```

**The problem seems to be in the polymorphic association, even though everything is ok in the DB, if I call @reseller.admin I get nil. Is this because we have two STI hierarchies with polymorphic association between them? Is this supported in Rails and if not, does anyone have an idea how to resolve/rework this? Thanks in advance.**

Code here:

```
class BaseReseller < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name "resellers"

  acts_as_nested_set

  belongs_to :admin, :polymorphic => true 
  has_many :users, :as => :owner
end

class IPSP < BaseReseller
end    

class Agent < BaseReseller
end

class Reseller < BaseReseller
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  has_one :administrable_owner, :as => :admin
end

class ResellerUser < User
end

class ResellersController < ApplicationController
  ... 
  def create
    @reseller = Reseller.new(params[:reseller])
    admin_user = ResellerUser.find(params[:reseller][:admin_id])
    @reseller.admin = admin_user
    @reseller.users << admin_user unless @reseller.users.include?(admin_user)
    if @reseller.save
      redirect_to @reseller
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  owner_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  owner_type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY index_users_on_owner_id (owner_id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE resellers (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  admin_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  parent_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  rgt int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  lft int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  depth int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY index_resellers_on_admin_id (admin_id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the dual polymorphism is causing a problem, I suggest temporarily removing polymorphism from one of the hierarchies (and then the other) to see if you still have the issue. That will narrow down the scope of the problem.

Also, what do your schema defs look like? You might be missing a foreign key column.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with the DB schema. I think I haven't missed anything, but you can look anyways.

Comment: Fixed! Had a missing admin_type inside the resellers table.

Comment: Ok, I did unvote (removing the green tick). Can you shortly explain why? Thanks.

Comment: @EmilPetkov Please accept again (put the green tick back). By "upvote" I mean click the UP arrow above the green tick to indicate that the answer was helpful.